# Notifications on changes in SmartSheet

Tags: smartsheet-api

The API only seems to describe how to get other programs to control smartsheets, how do I get smartsheet to control other apps?

It seems to be possible, the `zapier` integration mentions that you can make an event "on new row".

In particular, it would be nice to get notifications on new rows and changes in dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cine, you are correct - the explicit objective of the Smartsheet API (as is with most APIs) is to provide access to and facilitate management of Smartsheet data and properties.  The API has no knowledge of other products and services - nor it should.

The Smartsheet connectors for Zapier, Azuqua, itduzzit and other similar "API orchestration" services allow users to create triggers on various Smartsheet events, like new rows or row updates... or take an action based on another event (e.g., create a new row or update an existing row).

In addition, we are in the process of developing webhooks (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webhook and http://resthooks.org/) and plan to make these available later this year.  Through webhooks you will be able to subscribe to notifications on Smartsheet events, like new rows, sheets, discussions, etc.